# CSW-113 Header Manipulation Issue reported by Fortify in java

Tags: spring

I have authentication token as response from rest Template and I'm using this token for another call and everything is working fine
But during Fortify Security test its showing error during header set

```java
HttpHeaders header=new HttpHeaders();
header.setBasicAuth("Authorization",token)-->showing issue
```

What I understood is before setting this you need to add validator to remove \r\n from the token if available. I tried using regex but nothing worked.

Please if anyone faced this issue in java/spring boot project please help me. I need solution
Thanks in advance

Comment: If you are using `setBasicAuth` this code is just wrong. As is should be `setBasicAuth(usrename, password)` instead of directly passing the token. Unless you are using `setBasicAuth(token)`. Or you mean `headers.set("Authorization", token);`.

Comment: Sorry I means headers.set("Authorization",token)
and token="Bearer "+"xyz..."

Comment: Why not use `setBearer` on the headers instead? I suspect that also might solve your warning.

Comment: Hey Denium, I tried using headers.setBearerAuth()
But still facing the problem.

Comment: You can try and replace the cr/lf stuff `token.replaceAll("\r\n");` but not sure if that would fix the warning (depends on what the scanner will detect.

Comment: Yeah I tried that as well but nothing happened...Fortify tool specifically look for some particular library or what???

Comment: Could be. I would use the String replace and ignore the message (or mark it or whatever).